# crop image when overlap in responsive web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i am creating a responsive web design containing images....i want to know if there is any way i can crop images when they overlap i.e if i have two images in one line image 1 and image 2
image 1 is at the left and image 2 is at right and i start lessening width of my browser, and when image 2 reaches image 1, image 2 starts cropping or hiding or whatever....how m i going to do that?
here is my code for what i am trying:

```
#logo{
float:right;
margin:88px 0 0 70px;
position:absolute;
}
#header-add{
float:right;
margin:35px -10% 0 0;
cursor:pointer;

}
```

Logo is image 1 and header-add is image 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than crop the image, I'd suggest simply setting your CSS to set the width of the images appropriately when the browser width is decreased. This way you don't have to worry about cropping.

For example (values arbitrary, but percentage-based, which I find best for responsive design):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #header-add {
        width: 40%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #header-add {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to set the width of the images via CSS, you can essentially "crop" the images if you enclose each of them in a `div` and you can set `overflow:hidden` on the div, and then set the width of the div in the CSS (like the aforementioned image width example).

Hope it helps!

**Addition:**
In answer to your comment about cropping from the left, here's how I would recommend doing it. The downside is that you have to add an explicit height on the div that crops the image, but it should work for you.

The HTML:

```
<div id="crop_div">
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="bar" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#crop_div {
    float: right;
    height: 100px; /* Needed since contents use absolute position */
    overflow: hidden; /* To crop the img inside of it */
    position: relative; /* Set for img position below */
    width: 400px;
}
#crop_div img {
    position: absolute; /* To anchor it on the right */
    right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #crop_div {
        width: 40%;
    }
}
```

Comment: close to the solution but still width:40% changes the height of the image also...i dont know why but it is changing

Comment: Yeah, changing the actual image width will change the height by default. If that's not desired, go with the `overflow:hidden` method on a div surrounding the images, and have your @media queries change width on that div, rather than the image.

Comment: yeah this overflow thing is working but in opposite direction, i want the image to be croped from left to right but currently it is being cropped from right to left...how can i change this?

Comment: but still that would be great if somehow i stop height of the image from changing as this really is a nice solution to that...

Comment: You could hard-code the height of the image (NOT recommended), but this would cause image distortion when the width changes. That's why I'd recommend wrapping the images in a div. You can choose to set explicit height on the div and it won't affect the image inside of it. And with `overflow:hidden`, it will crop off width while the div width shrinks, all the while keeping the image at the same physical size, just cropped.

Comment: thanks for your concern but last thing, how m i going to make it crop from left to right rather than right to left

Comment: I updated my answer with sample code for how to set up the HTML and CSS to crop the image from the left rather than the right. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[clip()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/clip) and [`overflow: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for masking for sure your content.

`min-width` and/or **`max-width`** to manage the width of each `div` when the sum of both would be too large for the width of the container.